# Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Unity Tweak Tool not working?

Tags: unity, 14.04

I've been trying to use Unity Tweak Tool to apply the Numix icon and GTK themes, but it won't work at all.

The only thing I've even done in Ubuntu after installing it is just using Compiz to make the top bar transparent. Would this cause it?

Answer (score 2):

Have same problem over here, tried with suggestion from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205981&page=2

After dist-upgrade, mostly seem to work.

Copied answer from thread:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-tweak-tool
remove ppa if installed in repository
delete the contents of "var/cache/apt/archives/"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
install unity-tweak-tool from Software Center
```

Comment: Wow.... your reply came from nowhere, but I've moved on to Debian Jessie now. Sorry.