# Unity Settings Deamon crash in 16.04 every time after boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, 16.04, crash

Each and every time I boot Ubuntu 16.04 the *Ubuntu experienced an internal error* window comes up. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu on a selfbuild machine (AMD / 64bit). The error pops up every time seconds after I logged in and before I actually could do anything.

I've searched the internet and found a couple of bugs like [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1326636) but those I found all seem to have been fixed.

The title of the Error reads: unity-settings-deamon crashed with SIGSEGV in up_exported_dae (can't read more since there is no word wrapping).

Since I suspect this having to do with the graphics card: It is the MSI GTX 970 used the machine.

Edit: There I one more thing I noticed when booting: The purple screen appears pretty fast but then seems to be somewhat locked. I have to wait a couple of seconds before I can actually type in my password.

Comment: seems to be this bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1546641

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bring your system up-to-date, reinstall the unity-settings-daemon and reboot your system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-settings-daemon
sudo reboot
```

This should already solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I followed your steps and it seems the crash window doesn't show up anymore. But still the purple window hangs for about 10 seconds before I can enter a password, which is a bit of a nuisance but might be something for another question.

Comment: Yes, 10 seconds are pretty long...you should open a new question...

Comment: I did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/790470/16-04-freezes-shortly-on-purple-screen