# 16.04 freezes shortly on purple screen

Tags: boot, graphics, 16.04

System Spec: Self build PC, AMD 64 bit, NVidia GTX 970 (using the NVidia binary driver - version 367.27 from nvidia-367), fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.

Whenever I boot Ubuntu the purple screen is shown quickly but then freezes for about 10-20 seconds. In this time I see a blank purple screen (instead of my custom desktop background image) and mouse and keyboard do not respond. After the frosty times are over, the desktop image appears and I can actually enter the password and log on.

Besides this problem everything seems to be running smoothly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

`systemd-analyze` returns

```
Startup finished in 13.890s (firmware) + 4.092s (loader) + 2.366s (kernel) + 30.312s (userspace) = 50.661s
```

`systemd-analyze blame` returns

```
           29.516s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           28.253s upower.service
           325ms dev-sda2.device
           155ms ModemManager.service
           124ms accounts-daemon.service
           121ms networking.service
           118ms NetworkManager.service
           110ms snapd.refresh.service
           109ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           107ms systemd-logind.service
            98ms systemd-localed.service
            87ms apparmor.service
            80ms grub-common.service
            78ms irqbalance.service
            74ms apport.service
            72ms thermald.service
            69ms avahi-daemon.service
            65ms speech-dispatcher.service
            60ms systemd-journald.service
            51ms gpu-manager.service
            51ms ondemand.service
            50ms console-setup.service
            46ms lightdm.service
            39ms rsyslog.service
            34ms udisks2.service
            31ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AAB0\x2dE948.service
            24ms systemd-modules-load.service
            22ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            22ms plymouth-start.service
            20ms dev-hugepages.mount
            18ms alsa-restore.service
            18ms systemd-udevd.service
            17ms user@1000.service
            17ms dev-mqueue.mount
            16ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
            ... (continued)
```

Comment: I can't suggest a solution, but run the following two terminal commands to see details about the boot time: 'systemd-analyze' and 'systemd-analyze blame'... It could be a problem with NVidia or any other hardware device...

Comment: For me, this is what I see after a long purple screen delay (once logged in an running the commands):  http://pastebin.com/qDnZ2qs0

It's pretty disconcerting that the kernel is taking 32+ seconds to boot.

Comment: @Neni Thanks again for your efforts in finding a solution. After running these commands I guess its the network taking so long? Is there anything I can do about it? I'm connected via cable to my router.