# Fresh Installation of 16.04 and everything seems broken

Tags: boot, usb, 16.04, crash

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a self-built new machine (single boot). I have been using 14.04 on a different machine for about 2 years without ever having any problems. Since I need to do some heavy lifting now, I got myself new hardware. Here the specs: MSI 7693-040R 970 Gaming, AMD FX 8350, GTX 970 4G, 16 MB RAM, 500GB SSD. BIOS runs in UEFI mode.

I've been searching around now for two weeks in order to solve my issues but to no avail. Here are the problems I'm facing:

1. Very slow boot time ([16.04 freezes shortly on purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790470/16-04-freezes-shortly-on-purple-screen))
2. unity-settings-deamon crashes every time after boot ([Unity Settings Deamon crash in 16.04 every time after boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790326/unity-settings-deamon-crash-in-16-04-every-time-after-boot))
3. USB ports often seem to hang (I'm using a wireless-dongle for mouse and keyboard and they sometimes just freeze)
4. Not much of a problem, but might be something related: When I boot and come to the purple screen, my desktop image is shown only after a very long delay.

My questions are:

1. How do I find out if I'am facing these problems due to bad hardware?
2. Is there a chance that wiping the machine and installing 14.04 will solve these problems?

Since I could not find any solutions even after long hours of searching I am actually quite desperate by now and thinking about getting back to Win7.

Comment: When you say "Fresh install" you mean totally from scratch? Not upgrading from 14.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

Allegedly, AMD support dropped off in 16.04 - and isn't due to return anytime soon. 
But neither of my machines have anything AMD, and I still had other problems.
I'd be willing to bet your problem is not due to your hardware - but live booting/reinstalling an older distro will certainly help you deduce that.

The first thing I would try, if I were you - is to install a newer kernel. 
Try 4.5 - upgrading the kernel fixed a few things for me.

Second, you may want to roll back to 14.04 - or in my honest opinion, 15.10 was solid, and will be my choice for rolling back, if it really comes down to it.