# Ubuntu 16.04 themes not working after cloning HD

Tags: 16.04, themes

I cloned my hard disk to a SSD Hard Disk using Clonezilla and after booting up into it my Themes don't work I saw in an article on [this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762112/ubuntu-15-10-16-04-theme-doesnt-change) giving a solution back in September. It works only when I log out and in but if I reboot. I come back to the same result. The themes are not working. Any Suggestions?

when themes were working fine: 
processing the command

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity-settings-daemon
[sudo] password for stevelilley: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpango1.0-0 ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/496 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 290332 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity-settings-daemon_15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity-settings-daemon (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) over (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-settings-daemon (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
```

When themes were not working in Ubuntu 16.04
Processing the command

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity-settings-daemon
[sudo] password for stevelilley: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/496 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 313357 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity-settings-daemon_15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity-settings-daemon (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) over (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.48.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up unity-settings-daemon (15.04.1+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
```

The autoremove command:

```
sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for stevelilley: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56234/discussion-on-question-by-steve-l-ubuntu-16-04-themes-not-working-after-cloning).

Comment: I've discovered what cause the issue with the Themes using an SSD drive (probably also with freezing of the screen during login). The problem occurs if I login in too fast. I have done 7 logins over the last 2 days where I have waited 5-7 seconds after the login page appears (ie: when the screen resets to full screen not when it fills only 90% of the screen). Then I put in the login password and hit enter, only then the computer loads up with the correct themes. Just now I tried a quick login (ie: not waiting 5-7 seconds) and this mucked up the themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments and chat discussion under your question:

**Run these commands to fully update and upgrade your system:**

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt apt full-upgrade
$ sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This will upgrade and update your system packages.

Comment: By upgrading and updating the system applications that are not working properly.  I give the steps in comments, which I was sure would work.  The upgrading and updating.  It was verified by the user responding after performing the steps.  See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36377323#36377323 .

Comment: Noted, didn't see the chat transcript. I'd still throw in a link to them in the answer itself for other curious people. :)

Comment: @KazWolfe Thanks for pointing out the missing information.  I hadn't realized the chat discussion was under the Question instead of the answer.  I'm updating the answer again to make this clearer.