# ubuntu16.04 theme not working after reboot

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons, themes

I've set the theme `Ambiance` as the default theme and I expected the desktop to be like this
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mop4r.jpg)
However, every time I boot into system I got was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l10Wx.png)

The strangest thing is that if I logout and login everything is fine and I can get the expected desktop.

All this happened after I cloned the partition where ubuntu lies to a new SSD.
I tried the following methods, but no use:

- deleted other themes except Ambiance. (Seems stupid but I was driven nuts then)
- looked up post on this question [themes-not-working-after-cloning-hd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896708/ubuntu-16-04-themes-not-working-after-cloning-hd)
- [reset using unity-tweak-tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769384/how-to-restore-reset-unity-after-messing-up-with-unity-tweak-tool-ubuntu-16-0)

Any idea how to fix this? Now I just want to restore the default theme after messing up the Unity desktop. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: I would try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix tried but issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happened but I figured out a way to make things right.

To set the theme and icon-theme, say `Ambiance` and `Paper`, change the `settings.ini` in the `~/.config/` directory like this:

`[Settings]
gtk-font-name=Noto Sans 10
gtk-theme-name=Ambiance
gtk-icon-theme-name=Paper
gtk-fallback-icon-theme=gnome
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-button-images=1`

The names of themes and icon-themes can be found in the file `index.theme` in their corresponding dirs.

The themes and icon-themes are located in the `/usr/share/themes` and `/usr/share/icons`.